# inserting a faces (JSF) EL element on an iframe

Tags: jsf, el

I have an iframe like this

```
<iframe  src="path/of/destiny"></iframe>
```

and I want to write something like this

```
<iframe  src="path/of/destiny?#{myParameter}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible if you're using Facelets as view technology. But since you're asking this question, I assume that you're still using the legacy JSP as view technology. JSP doesn't allow deferred EL (`#{}`) in template text as Facelets does. You can however use standard EL (`${}`) in template text.

```
<iframe src="path/of/destiny?${myParameter}"></iframe>
```

You only need to take into account that whenever this has to be obtained as a JSF managed bean property like `${bean.myParameter}`, that this bean is already been created and available in the scope. You can ensure this by calling `#{bean.something}` in a fullworthy JSF component somewhere *before* the line with the `<iframe>`. The `#{}` will create the bean if not created yet.